# Cannot find main class in minecraft plugin

Tags: java, plugins, jar, minecraft

I have compiled this simple plugin
[Plugin.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrWGT.png)
[plugin.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRRX7.png)
Compiler is Maven
And I made it in VSCode
It still shows this error:

```
20:42:08 ERROR]: [ModernPluginLoadingStrategy] Could not load plugin 'bettercommands-0.1.jar' in folder 'plugins'
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: Cannot find main class `net.vitekform.bettercommands.Plugin.class'
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:80) ~[purpur-api-1.19.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at io.papermc.paper.plugin.provider.type.spigot.SpigotPluginProvider.createInstance(SpigotPluginProvider.java:123) ~[purpur-1.19.4.jar:git-Purpur-1975]
at io.papermc.paper.plugin.provider.type.spigot.SpigotPluginProvider.createInstance(SpigotPluginProvider.java:35) ~[purpur-1.19.4.jar:git-Purpur-1975]
at io.papermc.paper.plugin.entrypoint.strategy.modern.ModernPluginLoadingStrategy.loadProviders(ModernPluginLoadingStrategy.java:116) ~[purpur-1.19.4.jar:git-Purpur-1975]
at io.papermc.paper.plugin.storage.SimpleProviderStorage.enter(SimpleProviderStorage.java:39) ~[purpur-1.19.4.jar:git-Purpur-1975]
at io.papermc.paper.plugin.entrypoint.LaunchEntryPointHandler.enter(LaunchEntryPointHandler.java:36) ~[purpur-1.19.4.jar:git-Purpur-1975]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_19_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:438) ~[purpur-1.19.4.jar:git-Purpur-1975]
at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.initServer(DedicatedServer.java:310) ~[purpur-1.19.4.jar:git-Purpur-1975]
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.runServer(MinecraftServer.java:1120) ~[purpur-1.19.4.jar:git-Purpur-1975]
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$spin$0(MinecraftServer.java:325) ~[purpur-1.19.4.jar:git-Purpur-1975]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.vitekform.bettercommands.Plugin.class
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.loadClass0(PluginClassLoader.java:185) ~[purpur-api-1.19.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:152) ~[purpur-api-1.19.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467) ~[?:?]
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:78) ~[purpur-api-1.19.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
... 10 more
```

If somebody knows how to fix this i will be happy

Comment: Did you set the .class file directly in the plugins directory ? Or did you create some sub directories ? I never tried to install minecraft plugins but I think the path of the class file should be : <root>/plugins/net/vitekform/bettercommands/Plugin.class

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add the `.java` at this end of the of the path. Like that :

```yaml
name: bettercommands
main: net.vitekform.bettercommands.Plugin
version: 0.1
api-version: 1.15
```

Comment: I tryed that already it shows the same error

Comment: I have fixed it. So no more problem